# Understanding the & operator in templates

Tags: c++

so im currently reading *sams Teach yourself C++* and am unable to figure out when and why the & operator is used, as it seems like it would be uneccesary in many cases like so:

```
template <typename objectType>   
objectType & GetMax (const objectType & value1, const objectType & value2)    
{
    if (value1 > value2)  
        return value1;    
    else  
        return value2;
};
```

Another example:

```
Template <typename T>  
class myTemplateClass  
{  
public:   
    void SetVariable (T& newValue) {m_Value = newValue; };

    T& GetValue() {return m_Value;};

private:   
    T m_Value;  
};
```

Please help me understand why &, which I know gets the address of the data type, is here! its definately not making learning the STL any easier.......... THANKS! =)

Comment: Confusingly, it's not the same & you know which gets the address of an object. It's a whole different use.

Comment: you need a good book about C++... and don't lauch yourself into templates yet, wait until you know what references are, at the very least.

Answer (score 8):

That's not an operator, and it's not (directly) related to templates.

It's a type modifier, creating (or indicating or denoting or forming) a reference, just like `*` creates a pointer.

Much of the time, it's an optimization rather than a necessity.  <strike>Two</strike> Three cases where it is necessary:

- In the copy-constructor, it's needed to avoid infinite recursion:

  ```
  class X
  {
       //X(X);
       // pass by value, the formal parameter is a copy of the actual parameter
       // the copy constructor must be called to make the copy

       X(const X&); // pass by reference, ok, no copy constructor call necessary
  };
  ```

  Const references in general save having to copy a large object, which is a useful optimization with no surprising behavior.
- When the return type of a function, especially `operator[]` overload, must appear on the left hand side of an expression:

  ```
  class Container
  {
       //Element operator[](int index);
       // problematic because c[i] is a temporary
       // so c[i] = 5; doesn't actually modify the collection, like it would with an array

       Element& operator[](int index); // correct
  ```

  };

  As a similar case, for operators that mutate their left operand, like compound assignment and stream insertion, it's necessary to use a non-const reference parameter.

Any other cases (e.g. output arguments) can (and I think should) be handled with pointers, since a function call that LOOKS like pass-by-value but changes its argument violates the principle of least-surprise.  Perfect example: `auto_ptr<int> a = new int(5); f(a); /* is a still valid !?! */`

Which brings us to case 3, (created because somebody used non-const references outside of operators):

- In templates, when the actual type might by `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, a reference is needed to avoid inferring a type that destroys the original:

  ```
  auto_ptr<int> a = new int(5);

  //template<typename T>
  //void dump_target( T handle ) { cout << *item; }
  // bad: dump_target(a); destroys *a

  template<typename T>
  void dump_target( const T& handle ) { cout << *item; } // correct
  ```